# get_meta_tags - if else

Tags: php, if-statement

I have:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags("https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
<div>
    <h1><?php echo $tags['filter-title'] ?></h1>
<div>
```

How I can add if else, If the meta tag 'filter-title' doesn't exist and I only want to display the text "Filtering" instead?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I'm trying to display the value of one meta tag directly on the page, like the title h1. I have a working code, but so far terribly slow. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Comment: So you are trying to get the meta tags _of_ a page dynamically created by this script, _in_ the same script? Then I am surprised that it is working at all, I’d expect that to produce an endless loop.

Comment: ....like you would do it for any other array?

Comment: CBroe: Yes, it creates an endless loop. And that's the problem I'm solving :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check for the existence of an array key use `array_key_exists( 'keyName', $array )`.

Like this:

```
<h1><?php echo ( array_key_exists( 'filter-title', $tags ) ) ? $tags['filter-title'] : 'no filter title found'); ?></h1>
```

You can substitute whatever you like in place of 'no filter title found'.

Comment: Thx but syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: one ) missing :)

Answer (score 1):

@wetmarble's answer can be shortened to this:

```
<h1><?= $tags['filter-title'] ?? 'no filter title found'; ?></h1>
```